# conditional automated clicking software

Tags: automation

I'm looking for some software/program/tool that can click based on criteria I give it, such as, go look at the value of the number here, if it's equal to x, click on z.

So the criteria is not time..

Does that exist or should I develop it?

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: Maybe this?...http://www.ptfbpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for Automated Testing since this is what you want to do. I use TestComplete at work and with this you could do what you want. It is not quite cheap but does the job quite well. You can get a free copy to decide for yourself if this is worth a buy.

http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing/

Answer (score -1):

I found this: [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/).

> Automate Firefox. Record and replay repetitious work. If you love the Firefox web browser, but are tired of repetitive tasks like visiting the same sites every days, filling out forms, and remembering passwords, then iMacros for Firefox is the solution you’ve been dreaming of!